# Manage session across two app servers

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security, single-sign-on

I have a legacy application that runs on Spring 1.0 with Acegi security on JBoss 4. Our plan is to migrate one subset of the application to Tomacat 7 and Spring 4. The user will login to the legacy application but if they want to navigate to the subset that is being migrated they would be redirected to the new app.

My question is how would I maintain session information between the two so that the user can seamlessly navigate between the two apps and maintain SSO. There would be no other information exchanged between the two servers. One constraint we have is that we have to make minimal changes to the existing legacy app.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't seemlessly maintain session information as far as I can tell.

You might be able to get insanely lucky by configuring JBoss and Tomcat to be clustered [using Tomcat's clustering](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) (and assuming that the Tomcat version shipped with JBoss is compatible with the standalone Tomcat you are running), and then [enabling SSO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Single%20Sign%20On) on both JBoss and Tomcat, but then you have to be very careful not to place anything in your JBoss session that is not going to be loadable by the standalone Tomcat instance.

You are probably better-off implementing some other solution like using SAML that will likely be less fragile.

You said you didn't want to make too many changes, but if you are willing to get your hands dirty, you could use a shared URL-space between the web applications, use different session id cookies, and then cross-check incoming requests for unauthenticated users by calling-over to the "other" server to fetch their authentication information (which you'll have to make available in the session in some way). I'd advise against storing passwords in the user's session.. instead allow one application to obtain the username of the user in the other application using the session cookie from the first. Trust that the username is accurate and that the user has been correctly authenticated already in the first application, then perform an auto-login into the second.

Whatever you do, it's going to get messy, since your requirements are fairly messy.